# Collectors.toUnmodifiableList in java-10

Tags: java, java-stream, java-10

How do you create an `Unmodifiable` List/Set/Map with `Collectors.toList/toSet/toMap`, since `toList` (and the like) are document as :

> There are no guarantees on the **type**, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned

*Before* java-10 you have to provide a `Function` with `Collectors.collectingAndThen`, for example:

```
 List<Integer> result = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.toList(),
                    x -> Collections.unmodifiableList(x)));
```

Comment: In Java 9 you can also write `List.of(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4).stream().toArray(Integer[]::new));`

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov right. I am aware of that, internally btw they do the same thing `list -> (List<T>)List.of(list.toArray())`, obviously since you can't create a generic array, they have to cast..

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov and even in Java 8, you can write `Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4)` instead of `Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4).stream()` and, of course, in Java 9, you can do it even simpler by writing `List.of(1, 2, 3, 4)` in the first place…

Comment: @Holger `Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)` should be read as **some list**.

Comment: What is the point of `Collectors.unmodifiableList()` in the first place? It guarantees that the list is unmodifiable. But `Collectors.toList()` already *can* be unmodifiable. So instead of continuing to say there's no guarantee with `toList`, why not make `toList` return an unmodifiable list and document it as such?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException right, there was a comment from Stuart Marks that they *plan* for this, but since it is not documented as such, they probably introduces this one to make it clear. Since `toList` is not documented to return anything specific, it could in future return an `ArrayList` for example

Comment: @DodgyCodeException It’s a pity that `toList()` still returns a mutable list, likely raising the amount of code that wrongly relies on this property. But even if `toList()` now returned an immutable list, it was fundamentally different to `toUnmodifiableList()`, as the former still doesn’t specify the type and properties of the returned list, while the latter makes specific guarantees which the user can rely on. Besides that, the list type returned by `toUnmodifiableList()` will be the same as with `List.of(…)`, disallowing `null`, not only as element, but even as argument to query methods.

Comment: And it would be quiet surprising if `toList()` returned a list type with such a special behavior. Being immutable is clearly within the things that a programmer should expect, throwing an NPE on `contains(null)` perhaps not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With Java 10, this is much easier and a lot more readable:

```
List<Integer> result = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
```

Internally, it's the same thing as `Collectors.collectingAndThen`, but returns an instance of unmodifiable `List` that was added in Java 9.

Answer (score 8):

Additionally to clear out a documented difference between the two(`collectingAndThen` vs `toUnmodifiableList`) implementations :

> The `Collectors.toUnmodifiableList` would return a Collector that
>   disallows null values and will throw `NullPointerException` if it is
>   presented with a **`null`** value.

```
static void additionsToCollector() {
    // this works fine unless you try and operate on the null element
    var previous = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, null)
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), Collections::unmodifiableList));

    // next up ready to face an NPE
    var current = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, null).collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
}
```

and furthermore, that's owing to the fact that the former constructs an instance of `Collections.UnmodifiableRandomAccessList` while the latter constructs an instance of `ImmutableCollections.ListN` which adds to the list of attributes brought to the table with [static factory methods.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#immutable)

Comment: right, but that is really a property of `List.of` and the like, still, +1

Comment: @Eugene Agreed, just thought one should be clear of the difference in implementation. Not exactly the same thing after all ;)

Answer (score 4):

## `Stream#toList`

[Java 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_16) adds a method on the [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) interface: [`toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()). To quote the Javadoc:

> The returned `List` is unmodifiable; calls to any mutator method will always cause `UnsupportedOperationException` to be thrown.

Not just more convenient than [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html), this method has some goodies like better performance on parallel streams.

> In particular with parallel() -- as it avoids result copying.
> Benchmark is a few simple ops on 100K elem stream of Long.

[image: Java Mission Control toList performance]

For a further reading please go to: http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2020/12/jdk16-stream-to-list.html

In resume the link states something like this.

> Gotcha: It may be tempting to go into one's code base and use
> stream.toList() as a drop-in replacement for
> stream.collect(Collectors.toList()), but there may be differences in
> behavior if the code has a direct or indirect dependency on the
> implementation of stream.collect(Collectors.toList()) returning an
> ArrayList. Some of the key differences between the List returned by
> stream.collect(Collectors.toList()) and stream.toList() are spelled
> out in the remainder of this post.
>
> The Javadoc-based documentation for Collectors.toList() states
> (emphasis added), "Returns a Collector that accumulates the input
> elements into a new List. There are no guarantees on the type,
> mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned..."
> Although there are no guarantees regarding the "type, mutability,
> serializability, or thread-safety" on the List provided by
> Collectors.toList(), it is expected that some may have realized it's
> currently an ArrayList and have used it in ways that depend on the
> characteristics of an ArrayList

What i understand is that the Stream.toList() it will result in a inmutable List.

> Stream.toList() provides a List implementation that is immutable (type
> ImmutableCollections.ListN that cannot be added to or sorted) similar
> to that provided by List.of() and in contrast to the mutable (can be
> changed and sorted) ArrayList provided by
> Stream.collect(Collectors.toList()). Any existing code depending on
> the ability to mutate the ArrayList returned by
> Stream.collect(Collectors.toList()) will not work with Stream.toList()
> and an UnsupportedOperationException will be thrown.
>
> Although the implementation nature of the Lists returned by
> Stream.collect(Collectors.toList()) and Stream.toList() are very
> different, they still both implement the List interface and so they
> are considered equal when compared using List.equals(Object)

And this method will allow nulls so starting from Java 16 we will have a

```
mutable/null-friendly----->Collectors.toList()
immutable/null-friendly--->Stream.toList()
immutable/null-hostile---->Collectors.toUnmodifiableList() //Naughty
```

[image: Twitter conversation]
It's great.

Comment: there is [much broader discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65741773/would-stream-tolist-perform-better-than-collectors-tolist) about this. Also check your facts about `null`

Comment: which facts? mate?

Comment: my bad. I should have not posted a comment at 2 AM. What I really wanted to say is the quote you made : _Stream.toList() provides a List implementation that is immutable (type ImmutableCollections.ListN..._ is wrong. If it would have been right, `Stream::toList` could have not accepted nulls, and this is not the case.

Comment: @Eugene it seems, it *is* the same `List` implementation, but now, it has an internal flag whether to allow `null` or not.

Comment: Exactly @Holger they are the same than ListN implementation but just with a flag indeed the comments i put are from the guys from Oracle.

Comment: Stream.toList() will allow nulls this conversation i had it with some guys from Open JDK by twitter :)

Answer (score 0):

## `List/Set/Map.copyOf`

You asked:

> How do you create an Unmodifiable List/Set/Map

As of Java 10, simply pass your existing list/set/map to:

- [`List.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection))
- [`Set.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection))
- [Map.copyOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#copyOf(java.util.Map))

These static methods return an [unmodifiable `List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable), [unmodifiable `Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#unmodifiable), or [unmodifiable `Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable), respectively. Read the details on those linked Javadoc pages.

- No nulls allowed.
- If the passed collection is already unmodifiable, that passed collection is simply returned, no further work, no new collection.

Note: If using the convenient [`Stream#toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) method in Java 16+ as described in [this other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65790710/642706), there is no point to this solution here, no need to call `List.copyOf`. The result of `toList` is already unmodifiable.