# Differences of Java 16's Stream.toList() and Stream.collect(Collectors.toList())?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors, java-16

[JDK 16 now includes a `toList()` method directly on `Stream` instances](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8180352). In previous Java versions, you always had to use the `collect` method and provide a `Collector` instance.

The new method is obviously fewer characters to type. Are both methods interchangeable or are there subtle differences one should be aware of?

```
var newList = someCollection.stream()
    .map(x -> mapX(x))
    .filter(x -> filterX(x))
    .toList();

// vs.

var oldList = someCollection.stream()
    .map(x -> mapX(x))
    .filter(x -> filterX(x))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(This question is similar to [Would Stream.toList() perform better than Collectors.toList()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65741773/would-stream-tolist-perform-better-than-collectors-tolist), but focused on behavior and not (only) on performance.)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

One difference is that `Stream.toList()` provides a `List` implementation that is immutable (type `ImmutableCollections.ListN` that cannot be added to or sorted) similar to that provided by `List.of()` and in contrast to the mutable (can be changed and sorted) `ArrayList` provided by `Stream.collect(Collectors.toList())`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Stream.of("Hello").toList();
        System.out.println(list);
        list.add("Hi");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Hello]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections.uoe(ImmutableCollections.java:142)
    at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$AbstractImmutableCollection.add(ImmutableCollections.java:147)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Please check [this article](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2020/12/jdk-16-stream-to-list-in-one-easy-call.html) for more details.

### Update:

Interestingly, `Stream.toList()` returns a `null`s-containing list successfully.

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> list = Stream.of(null, null).toList();
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[null, null]
```

On the other hand, `List.of(null, null)` throws `NullPointerException`.

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> list = List.of(null, null);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208)
    at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12.<init>(ImmutableCollections.java:453)
    at java.base/java.util.List.of(List.java:827)
    at Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

**Note:** I've used ***openjdk-16-ea+34_osx-x64*** to compile and execute the Java SE 16 code.

**Useful resources:**

1. JDK Bug#[JDK-8180352](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8180352)
2. [Calling Java varargs method with single null argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028059/calling-java-varargs-method-with-single-null-argument)

Comment: Does this subsequently mean that `.toList()` can never return a null-containing list, but `.collect(toList()` can? i.e. `Stream.of(null, null).toList()` throws, `Stream.of(null, null).collect(toList())` returns?

Comment: IIRC, `Collectors.toList()` is not guaranteed to give us a mutable list either. It just happens to do so in the Java versions we have seen so far.

Comment: @OleV.V. - Correct. The article linked in my answer mentions it as: `Although there are no guarantees regarding the “type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety” on the List provided by Collectors.toList(), it is expected that some may have realized it’s currently an ArrayList and have used it in ways that depend on the characteristics of an ArrayList.`

Comment: it's good that you edited, I have no idea how my comment was removed though :|

Comment: Nothing directed to the author, and maybe something for a new question, but isn't it strange that it returns a `List`, but you can't use half of the methods on that interface? Doesn't really implement that interface then, does it?

Comment: @Caramiriel The `List` interface was on purpose designed with a number of optional methods, that is, methods that implementing classes need not implement and that many implementations do not implement. You’re not the first to wonder.

Comment: It is not really a correct statement to say that `collect(toList())` returns a mutable list; the specification is very clear that it makes _no guarantees_ as to the mutability of the returned list.  The current implementation _happens to_ return an `ArrayList` _right now_, but the spec was written explicitly to allow that to change.  If you want a mutable list, use `toCollection(ArrayList::new)`.

Comment: It is unfortunate that `List` was not divided into `ReadableList` with `get()` etc. and `WritableList` with `set()`, `add()` etc., but it's too late to fix now. (note: I originally came here to suggest `toCollection(ArrayList::new)`, which is what I always use when I need a mutable list, but The Man Himself beat me to it. )

Comment: The new method Stream.toList() produces neither an unmodifiable list nor a shortcut to collect(toUnmodifiableList()), because toUnmodifiableList() doesn’t accept nulls.The implementation of Stream.toList() is not constrained by the Collector interface; therefore, Stream.toList() allocates less memory. https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/hidden-gems-jdk16-jdk17-jep     Can you Validate the above statements in the article ?

Comment: @ClementCherlin For advanced list APIs, please check [Eclipse Collections](https://eclipse.dev/collections/) - a much underrated Java data structure library.

Answer (score 60):

Here is a small table that summarizes the differences between `Stream.collect(Collectors.toList())`, `Stream.collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList())` and `Stream.toList()`:

| Method | Guarantees unmodifiability | Allows nulls | Since |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `collect(toList())` | No | Yes | Java 8 |
| `collect(toUnmodifiableList())` | Yes | No | Java 10 |
| `toList()` | Yes | Yes | Java 16 |

Another small difference:

```
// Compiles
List<CharSequence> list = Stream.of("hello", "world").collect(toList());

// Error
List<CharSequence> list = Stream.of("hello", "world").toList();
```

Comment: The new method Stream.toList() produces neither an unmodifiable list nor a shortcut to collect(toUnmodifiableList()), because toUnmodifiableList() doesn’t accept nulls.The implementation of Stream.toList() is not constrained by the Collector interface; therefore, Stream.toList() allocates less memory. That makes it optimal to use when the stream size is known in advance.  https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/hidden-gems-jdk16-jdk17-jep                                                    
 Can you Validate the above statements

Comment: I would add that the first one was introduced in Java 8, the 2nd in Java 10, and the 3rd in Java 16.

Comment: @deepakl.2000 on the contrary, Stream.toList() [guarantees an unmodifiable list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()). It is indeed not a shortcut to `Collectors.toUnmodifiableList())`.

Answer (score 17):

`.collect(toList())` and `toList()` behave **different regarding sub type compatibility of the elements** in the created lists.

Have a look at the following alternatives:

- `List<Number> old = Stream.of(0).collect(Collectors.toList());` works fine, although we collect a stream of *Integer* into a list of *Number*.
- `List<Number> new = Stream.of(0).toList();` is the equivalent Java 16+ version, but it doesn't compile (`cannot convert from List<Integer> to List<Number>`; at least in ecj, the Eclipse Java compiler).

There are at least 2 workarounds to fix the compile error:

- Explicitly cast to the wanted type
  `List<Number> fix1 = Stream.of(0).map(Number.class::cast).toList();`
- allow sub types in the result collection:
  `List<? extends Number> fix2 = Stream.of(0).toList();`

To my understanding the root cause is as follows: The generic type T of the Java 16 `toList()` is the same as the generic type T of the Stream itself. The generic type T of Collectors.toList() however is propagated from the left hand side of the assignment. If those 2 types are different, you may see errors when  replacing all the old calls.

Comment: 1+, it happens in `javac` also, and probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77584226/1059372) is the "long" explanation.

Answer (score 4):

They differ in what they can process related to inheritance.

This answer really expands [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73210273/1059372), since it will be too long for a comment.

Suppose there are two classes:

```
static class Animal {

}

static class Dog extends Animal {

}
```

And such a method:

```
List<Animal> test(List<Dog> dogs) {

    Stream<Dog> stream = dogs.stream();
    Collector<Animal, ?, List<Animal>> collector = Collectors.toList();

    List<Animal> animals = stream.collect(collector);

    return animals;
}
```

Notice a few probably obvious things:

- `stream` is of type `Stream<Dog>`. The `Stream.class` is declared as `Stream<T> ...` , so `T` will be inferred to be a `Dog`.
- `stream::collect`  calls a method that is declared as: `<R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector);`

Notice the type: `? super T`, that is why we can pass a `Collector<Animal, ?, List<Animal>`: the first argument `Animal` is a super type of `T` (`Dog`).

This is kind of logic btw if you think what a collector is supposed to do. It must take some type and produce a `List` of those types (in our case). That "type" in our case is a `Dog` (but at the same time is an `Animal` too). The result from the collector is a `List<Animal>` and you *can* put dogs in such a `List`.

---

The same thing does not work with `toList`:

```
List<Animal> test(List<Dog> dogs) {
    Stream<Dog> stream = dogs.stream();
    List<Animal> animals = stream.toList();
    return animals;
}
```

You probably understand why already, its because `Stream::toList` is declared as : `default List<T> toList() { ... }`