# Convert a List String to an ArrayList Float with Stream in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Good afternoon, Community!

I have a List:

```java
List<String> rate = new ArrayList<>();
```

and I need to convert the data into a float if it can be done with java 8 stream.
I was doing it in the following way:

```java
float valueRate = Float.parseFloat(rate);
```

Comment: List rate = new ArrayList <> (); -  float valueRate = Float.parseFloat (rate);

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

- Given a list of strings floating point values.
- map them to a stream of `float` using `Float.valueOf()`
- and collect into a List.

```
List<String> list = List.of("1.2", "3.4", "2.5f");
List<Float> floats = list.stream().map(Float::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
    
System.out.println(floats);
```

Prints

```
[1.2, 3.4, 2.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Stream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) with [`Float.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) (to avoid autoboxing).

```
List<Float> res = rate.stream().map(Float::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

With Java 16:

```
List<Float> res = rate.stream().map(Float::valueOf).toList();
```

Comment: If possible, in all new answers, please include a note about [`Stream::toList`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65969919/10819573) available since Java-16.