# Why SonarQube shows this as Noncompliant code (Refactor the code so this stream pipeline is used.)?

Tags: java, stream, sonarqube, sonarlint

I have a few simple Java Streams in my code for these Streams SonarQube/Sonarlint shows as Noncompliant with the message:

```
Refactor the code so this stream pipeline is used.
```

Following are my Java Methods/Streams:

```
private static List<String> format(List<String> input) {
    return input.stream().map(i -> DomainName + "/path/file-" + i).toList();
}
```

Another Noncompliant code sample is:

```
private static List<String> format1(List<String> input) {
    return input.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).toList();
}
```

I believe these are simple Java Streams and they are working as expected for my requirement so not sure what's wrong with this. Can someone please explain what's wrong with this and how to fix the SonarQube issue?

Following is the Bug which is thrown by SonarQube:
[image]

**Another Clarification**

Which of the below is good to use as per Sonar and coding perspective?

I am currently creating a List something like this:

```
final List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Update**

So SonarCube tells me to declare it as `var` so is it good to change it to

1. `var myList = new ArrayList<>();` or
2. `final var myList = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Probably it's because `toList` returns an unmodifiable list, whereas `collect(Collectors.toList())` returns a modifiable `ArrayList` instead, but I'm only guessing. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65969919/differences-of-java-16s-stream-tolist-and-stream-collectcollectors-tolist) for reference

Comment: Huh that's weird. Is it not aware of what's new in Java 16? What if you change `toList()` to `collect(Collectors.toList())`? Does that work?

Comment: @Sweeper  I thought so hence I tried to change it to `input.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toList())` but If I do that then I get another issue `"Stream.toList()" method should be used instead of "collectors" when unmodifiable list needed` and it informs me to use `toList`. It will give me one or another issue.

Comment: Is that the warning from your IDE or also a Sonar issue? If it's from the IDE, then it looks like there's some discrepancies in the rules. This seems like a false positive to me, so maybe it would be best to just suppress the Sonar warning?

Comment: @QBrute Thanks a lot for your response. Sure will do the same. I have one more small doubt regarding the SonarLint, I have posted the same at the bottom of this question above. If possible can you please have a look and provide some suggestion?

Comment: @QBrute The issue is not coming from the IDE Problems rather my organization's SonarQube deployment. It's throwing as `bug`. I have added a screenshot of it in the question. Can you please once check and let me know how can I fix it?