# Convert list to string using Java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I created a for each loop  and I get list of price code  but I want to
get same things without using any loop and perform this operation
using java8 for your reference I post my old code.
I want to change only this position  of my code.

```
List<ItemPriceCode> itemPriceCodes = item.getItemPriceCodes();
          List<String> priceCodeList = new ArrayList<String>();                              
          for (ItemPriceCode ipc : itemPriceCodes) {
              //get the string value from the list
               priceCodeList.add(ipc.getPriceCode());
        }
```

But I do not want to use any loop I want to get same result without
using any loop . To over come from this issue I try this way but I am
not get any success.

```
itemPriceCodes.stream().map(n -> String.valueOf(n)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here This is my full code of this function

```
private Item getItemManufacturerPriceCodes(Item item) {
          List<ItemPriceCode> itemPriceCodes = item.getItemPriceCodes();
          List<String> priceCodeList = new ArrayList<String>();
          for (ItemPriceCode ipc : itemPriceCodes) {
              //get the string value from the list
               priceCodeList.add(ipc.getPriceCode());
        }
          //pass this string value in query
          List<ManufacturerPriceCodes>mpc = manufacturerPriceCodesRepository.
                 findByManufacturerIDAndPriceCodeInAndRecordDeleted(item.getManufacturerID(),priceCodeList,NOT_DELETED);
          
          //Convert list to map
          Map<String, ManufacturerPriceCodes> ipcToMFPNameMap = mpc.stream().collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(ManufacturerPriceCodes :: getPriceCode,Function.identity()));// Object



         for (ItemPriceCode ipcs : itemPriceCodes) {
              ipcs.setManufacturerPriceCode(ipcToMFPNameMap.getClass().getName());
        }
          item.getItemPriceCodes()
          .removeIf(ipcs -> DELETED.equals(ipcs.getRecordDeleted()));
      return item;      
      }
```

Answer (score 6):

It should be

```
List<String> priceCodeList = itemPriceCodes.stream().map(ItemPriceCode::getPriceCode)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT:
Java 16+

```
List<String> priceCodeList = itemPriceCodes.stream().map(ItemPriceCode::getPriceCode)).toList()
```

Although this would return an immutable list.

Furthur reading: [Differences of Java 16's Stream.toList() and Stream.collect(Collectors.toList())?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65969919/differences-of-java-16s-stream-tolist-and-stream-collectcollectors-tolist)

Although it doesn't seem necessary considering the use case if you want to use `String.valueOf()` you need to override `toString` accordingly in your class, as `String.valueOf()` uses it to get the string representation.

Definition of valueOf()

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {  
   return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();  
}
```

Thus to make your code work.. add this in your class

```
class ItemPriceCode{
  .
  .
  .
  public String toString(){
     return this.getPriceCode();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can go further and change the `.collect(Collectors.toList())` and replace it with `.toList()`