# Why does Stream#toList's default implementation seem overcomplicated / suboptimal?

Tags: java, java-stream, java-16

Looking at the implementation for `Stream#toList`, I just noticed how overcomplicated and suboptimal it seemed.

Like mentioned in the javadoc just above, this `default` implementation is not used by most `Stream` implementation, however, it could have been otherwise in my opinion.

### The sources

```java
/**
 * Accumulates the elements of this stream into a {@code List}. The elements in
 * the list will be in this stream's encounter order, if one exists. The returned List
 * is unmodifiable; calls to any mutator method will always cause
 * {@code UnsupportedOperationException} to be thrown. There are no
 * guarantees on the implementation type or serializability of the returned List.
 *
 * <p>The returned instance may be <a href="{@docRoot}/java.base/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html">value-based</a>.
 * Callers should make no assumptions about the identity of the returned instances.
 * Identity-sensitive operations on these instances (reference equality ({@code ==}),
 * identity hash code, and synchronization) are unreliable and should be avoided.
 *
 * <p>This is a <a href="package-summary.html#StreamOps">terminal operation</a>.
 *
 * @apiNote If more control over the returned object is required, use
 * {@link Collectors#toCollection(Supplier)}.
 *
 * @implSpec The implementation in this interface returns a List produced as if by the following:
 * <pre>{@code
 * Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(this.toArray())))
 * }</pre>
 *
 * @implNote Most instances of Stream will override this method and provide an implementation
 * that is highly optimized compared to the implementation in this interface.
 *
 * @return a List containing the stream elements
 *
 * @since 16
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
default List<T> toList() {
    return (List<T>) Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(this.toArray())));
}
```

### My idea of what would be better

```java
return (List<T>) Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(this.toArray()));
```

### Or even

```java
return Arrays.asList(this.toArray()));
```

### IntelliJ's proposal

```java
return (List<T>) List.of(this.toArray());
```

Is there any good reason for the implementation in the JDK sources?

Comment: This was [discussed here under comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65741773/would-stream-tolist-perform-better-than-collectors-tolist#comment116293110_65741773) as well.

Comment: You're misreading the code.  This is not the implementation you think it is; this is the default implementation used for third-party implementations of `Stream` that do not provide an implementation of `toList`.  The JDK does something very different; see `ReferencePipeline::toList` for the actual implementation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `toArray` method might be implemented to return an array that is then mutated afterwards, which would effectively make the returned list not immutable. That's why an explicit copy by creating a new `ArrayList` is done.

It's essentially a defensive copy.

This was also discussed during the [review of this API](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/1026#discussion_r529183482), where Stuart Marks writes:

> As written it's true that the default implementation does perform apparently redundant copies, but we can't be assured that toArray() actually returns a freshly created array. Thus, we wrap it using Arrays.asList and then copy it using the ArrayList constructor. This is unfortunate but necessary to avoid situations where someone could hold a reference to the internal array of a List, allowing modification of a List that's supposed to be unmodifiable.

Comment: As of `List.of` version, it won't tolerate null elements in the stream. Actual `toList()` tolerates them.