# Java PriorityQueue initElementsFromCollection method

Tags: java, collections, priority-queue, heap

I'm having hard time digesting this particular code block from [java.util.PriorityQueue#initElementsFromCollection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Collection)) method.

```java
/**
 * Initializes queue array with elements from the given Collection.
 *
 * @param c the collection
 */
private void initFromCollection(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    initElementsFromCollection(c);
    heapify();
}

private void initElementsFromCollection(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    Object[] es = c.toArray();
    int len = es.length;
    if (c.getClass() != ArrayList.class)
        es = Arrays.copyOf(es, len, Object[].class);
    if (len == 1 || this.comparator != null)
        for (Object e : es)
            if (e == null)
                throw new NullPointerException();
    this.queue = ensureNonEmpty(es);
    this.size = len;
}
```

I can understand that the code here tries to build the Heap from the collection elements supplied via constructor but why are they checking the class type of `Collection` argument against `ArrayList` and again copying the elements, it has already been copied into `Object[] es` using `toArray`?

```java
    if (c.getClass() != ArrayList.class)
        es = Arrays.copyOf(es, len, Object[].class);
```

Is anything magical happening in `java.util.Arrays#copyOf(U[], int, java.lang.Class<? extends T[]>)` ?

`java-11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor (or rather its author) does not trust the incoming collection. The collection’s `toArray` method could violate the contract and return a shared array rather than creating a new one. This way, the caller could get hands on the internally used array of the constructed `PriorityQueue` instance.

So, the constructor makes another defensive copy, except when the incoming collection is an `ArrayList` exactly, i.e. not even a subclass of it. In other words, it trusts the `ArrayList`’s `toArray` implementation to adhere to the contract, to skip the additional copying step in this specific case. That’s why not even a subclass of `ArrayList` will be accepted, as a subclass could have overridden the `toArray` method.

A similar mistrust has been displayed in the default implementation of `Stream.toList()` as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66946013/2711488) and the comment section beneath [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65741773/2711488).

The default implementation has been specified as

```java
default List<T> toList() {
    return (List<T>) Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(this.toArray())));
}
```

because it distrust the `toArray()` implementation of 3rd party `Stream` implementations (the JDK implementation overrides the `toList()` method anyway).

The penalty of this paranoia is even paid twice. In the past, `ArrayList`’s constructor did trust any incoming collection’s `toArray()` implementation, but today, it looks like

```java
public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    Object[] a = c.toArray();
    if ((size = a.length) != 0) {
        if (c.getClass() == ArrayList.class) {
            elementData = a;
        } else {
            elementData = Arrays.copyOf(a, size, Object[].class);
        }
    } else {
        // replace with empty array.
        elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
    }
}
```

doing exactly the same as you’ve seen in `PriorityQueue`’s constructor, only trust `toArray()` when the collection is exactly an `ArrayList`.

Since in the case of the `toList()`, the incoming collection is the result of `Arrays.asList(…)`, i.e. not an `ArrayList`, the `toArray()` method will make a copy, followed by `ArrayList`’s constructor making another copy. All that, while the original array is a new array anyway, for well behaving `Stream` implementations…

---

We can generalize the problem. The idiomatic initialization of collections, like `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(…))` or `new ArrayList<>(List.of(…))` or likewise for `PriorityQueue`, get the penalty of a defensive copy despite only using JDK collections which should have a correct `toArray` implementation.

I’d probably use `c.getClass().getClassLoader() != null` instead of `c.getClass() != ArrayList.class`, to trust all built-in collections, whose implementation has been loaded by the bootstrap loader. But perhaps, that test would turn out to be more expensive than the `ArrayList` test¹ or there are too many untrustworthy built-in collections…

¹ The key point is whether the optimizer understands the construct well enough to predict its outcome.

Comment: Got it. Appreciate your effort. It's like "If c.toArray incorrectly doesn't return Object[], copy it."

Comment: That was the old logic. Whether `toArray` incorrectly returned an the array other than `Object[]`, was easy to test. But whether the array incorrectly is a shared array, would be expensive to test. So it simply assumes that it could be shared, unless known to stem from a trusted implementation. Ironically, in the past, the implementation that under certain circumstances incorrectly returned an array not being `Object[]`, was a JDK class, i.e. the list returned by `Array.asList(…)`.