# How to add a string field to the List of string formed by stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a string field `userId`, I want to add it to the list of strings which is formed by stream like this `user.getFollowing.stream().toList()`

```java
public List<Post> getAllPosts(String userId) {
    User user = this.findUserById(userId);
    System.out.printf("Finding all posts created by %s%n", userId);
    
    if (user != null) {
        List<String> userList = user.getFollowing().stream().toList();

        userList.add(userId).stream().toList();

        List<Post> allPostsList = postService.findPostsCreatedByMultipleUsers(userList);
        System.out.printf("Returning %d posts created by %s%n", allPostsList.size(), userId);
        return allPostsList;
    } else {
        System.out.printf("Unable to find user by id %s%n", userId);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just want to add userId field to the list of string formed by stream (in this i somehow want to add user id ... user.getFollowing().stream.toList())

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, and try to format your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

There are several possible solutions:

1. `stream::toList` returns an immutable list, so if it is replaced by a mutable list, `userId` may be just added:

```java
List<String> userList = user.getFollowing().stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
userList.add(userId);
// ...
```

2. Use `Stream::concat` to concatenate two streams, the second is created from `userId` using `Stream.of`:

```java
List<String> userList = Stream.concat(
        user.getFollowing().stream(),
        Stream.of(userId)
    )
    .toList();
```

---

However, the simplest solution does not require Stream API at all:

```
List<String> userList = new ArrayList<>(user.getFollowing());
userList.add(userId);
```

Comment: `collect(Collectors.toList())` returns a list with [**no guarantees on** the type, **mutability**, serializability, or thread-safety](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()), so it should not be suggested as solution to get a mutable list. `collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))` would be a valid solution guaranteeing a mutable list. However, it’s a typical case of overengineering with streams. `List<String> userList = new ArrayList<>(user.getFollowing()); userList.add(userId);` does the job as well.

Comment: No guarantees, but still returning [ArrayList with `ArrayList::new`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#L280).  Also impressed by [`Stream::toList`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/Stream.java#L1198) implementation: `return (List<T>) Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(this.toArray())));`

Comment: It does return an `ArrayList` in the reference implementation, but you should not rely on implementation details, especially when the documentation explicitly says that it is not guaranteed. The `Stream::toList` implementation you’re referring to is the default implementation you’ll probably never encounter in practice. The actual implementation you’ll end up is far better. But still, the default [has been discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65741773/would-stream-tolist-perform-better-than-collectors-tolist#comment116293110_65741773).