# Is it necessary to copy a list to be safe?

Tags: java, list, collections

The implementation (and documentation) of [Stream.toList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) is like this:

```java
Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(this.toArray())))
```

I'm wondering why the list returned by `Arrays.asList` needs to be copied to a new `ArrayList`. Would it not be sufficient to just return the following?

```java
Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(this.toArray()))
```

I would like to know, if I write a method that returns a list that it creates like this, would there be any issues if I didn't bother to make a defensive copy of it?

Comment: To the person recommending "Close" due to being "opinion-based": how can it _possibly_ be opinion-based? It either is or isn't unsafe to omit copying the list. If it is unsafe, you should be able to describe a scenario whereby the safety can be compromised. If it is safe, you should be able to prove it. Nothing opinion-based there.

Comment: Probably because you have not defined with 'safe' means. What you consider safe someone else might consider unsafe. Until that is defined this question is a matter of opinion. It's also more than a little broad. Furthermore, what do you mean by "sufficient" in your first question? Sufficient for what? To compile? To run? To achieve the desired outcome? Something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### It has a purpose

> I'm wondering why the list returned by Arrays.asList needs to be copied to a new ArrayList. Would it not be sufficient to just return the following?

Which `.toArray()` are we talking about? If we're talking about the one from `j.u.Collection`, you're right: The javadoc of that `toArray()` method *guarantees* that it is a newly allocated array, hence, no need to make a defensive copy. However, that's not the `toArray()` involved here: We're talking about `j.u.s.Stream`'s `.toArray()`. Its javadoc is a lot shorter:

```
    /**
     * Returns an array containing the elements of this stream.
     *
     * <p>This is a <a href="package-summary.html#StreamOps">terminal
     * operation</a>.
     *
     * @return an array, whose {@linkplain Class#getComponentType runtime component
     * type} is {@code Object}, containing the elements of this stream
     */
```

Unlike `j.u.Collection toArray()`, this javadoc makes no notes either way about the nature of that array. Hence, evidently, the default impl in the `Stream` javadoc does not presume the array is necessarily 'safe' ('safe' in the sense: Will not later be modified).

I think you know, but just to be crystal clear:

`Arrays.asList` is almost always a mistake. It's a worst-of-both-worlds list: It creates a light wrapper around the array you pass to it. So, `set()` works (because `foo[x] = value;` is possible and indeed, is how that is implemented), but `.add()` doesn't (because you can't change the size of an array). The list is not immutable (i.e. if passing it to code outside of your direct control you need to extensively document, or, make a defensive copy), but also not a fully featured list. Use `List.of` instead, which makes fully immutable lists - lists you can pass around to whomever you like without worrying about losing control of integrity.

EDIT: And to explain why its `Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<...`) instead of `List.copyOf` - The immutable lists that those static methods on `List` make throw NPEs when `null` is in there, but streams can have `null`, so you can't use that. This edit brought to you by a comment from @Rob Spoor :)

### This is not as big an issue as you think, though

Note that the code you found is merely the default implementation - any particular implementation of stream is free to come up with a better way to do this. Just about every implementation you are bound to run into overrides the definition. For example, if you call an arraylist's `stream()`, you end up with this implementation instead, which is from streamops and is the same code path used by all the collections in the core libs. Hence, the actual code you end up using, is this:

```
    @Override
    public List<P_OUT> toList() {
        return SharedSecrets.getJavaUtilCollectionAccess()
        .listFromTrustedArrayNullsAllowed(this.toArray());
    }
```

'trusted array' here refers to the notion that the array passed to it is guaranteed not going to change out from under you. There is no way the compiler can enforce that guarantee, but arraylist's (and indeed, all non-broken collections, given that the javadoc of `j.u.Collection` demands it!) `toArray()` makes new arrays so it's safe to do that, and this is far more efficient (avoids a bunch of needless copies).

Comment: "Use `List.of` instead" is great advise if you know that no element will be `null`. Since `Stream`'s default method must assume the stream can contain `null` elements it cannot be used. That makes `Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array)))` a good alternative to create an unmodifiable list based on a potentially mutable array.

Comment: One can also note that the default `Stream.toList()` implementation (which was tacked on many years later) is likely a compromise where the priorities (from high to low) were 1) make absolutely sure this works with every single contract-abiding implementation that has been written over the last several years, 2) since this only exists for backwards compatibility and it'll often be overridden with better implementations, don't make it smarter or more complicated than it has to be, and 3) just make sure it's not _painfully_ slow. Personally, I find the implementation to be a good balance.

Comment: I don’t think that it is helpful to construct a difference between the contracts of `Collection.toArray` and `Stream.toArray`, both should return a new array. But there is some distrust about the correctness of 3rd part implementations, see [`ArrayList`’s constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77574918/2711488) for example which also makes a copy of the array returned by `Collection.toArray` when it doesn’t come from a trusted class (`ArrayList` itself).

Comment: @Holger I operate under the assumption that the javadoc of a method is the _canonical_ source of contract rules (here I use the term 'contract' as: These are rules that, if you break them, means your code is buggy; however, the type system cannot check it. In contrast to e.g. an interface, where the compiler _will_ refuse to compile it if you `implements X` and fail to implement one of the methods you must implement as per the def of interface X.). That's the proper approach, no? In which case - there really is a contract difference between the two, I'm afraid.

Comment: I certainly agree with you this difference shouldn't exist, but, it's there. Editing that javadoc _now_ is backwards incompatible; an impl of stream.toArray that fails to make a safe copy is technically correct (in that no contract stipulates that this is _incorrect_); after a javadoc update it would no longer be so. OpenJDK has bizarre ideas about backwards compatibility; they take it too seriously in cases like this, and not seriously enough when it's their own pet projects. Such breaking `.setAccessible` on all reflective types. Point being - they won't change this in my experience.

Comment: The documentation also doesn’t say that implementors were allowed to keep a reference to the returned array. So why should implementors be allowed to make more assumptions than the callers? By the way, it has been acknowledged in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65741773/would-stream-tolist-perform-better-than-collectors-tolist#comment116307258_65741773) that the scenario, this defensive copy is protecting against, is considered a violation of the spec.

Comment: @Holger Implementors can do whatever they want once they've adhered to all spelled out in the javadoc. That's the point of the abstraction layer. Any restrictions and stipulations must be specified (presumably, in the javadoc, because, where else?); if they aren't, they don't exist. Your link to the comment by Stuart Marks is quite interesting; it seems like Stuart is wrong. I assume Stuart is a homo sapiens, and therefore, fallible. I've asked for clarification there; maybe team OpenJDK considers a different place as canonical repository of API contracts and stipulations.

Comment: Even the documentation authors are homo sapiens and it’s never a good idea to counteract obvious intent just because someone feels like the intent has not been spelled out explicitly enough. You are the first one I ever encountered since the introduction of the Stream API who thinks that keeping a reference to the array was a legal behavior for implementors.

Comment: @Holger I have asked about this invisible spec Stuart is talking about on core-lib-dev. I don't have openJDK commit rights, but if it was a normal project I'd have filed a PR to add the same stipulation rider the Collection.toArray javadoc has, to the Stream.toArray javadoc.

Answer (score 3):

### Unmodifiable *view* backed by a modifiable collection

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#unmodview) (emphasis mine):

> An unmodifiable view collection is a collection that is unmodifiable and that is also a view onto a backing collection. Its mutator methods throw UnsupportedOperationException, as described above, while reading and querying methods are delegated to the backing collection. The effect is to provide read-only access to the backing collection. This is useful for a component to provide users with read access to an internal collection, while preventing them from modifying such collections unexpectedly. Examples of unmodifiable view collections are those returned by the Collections.unmodifiableCollection, Collections.unmodifiableList, and related methods.

> Note that **changes to the backing collection might still be possible, and if they occur, they are visible through the unmodifiable view**. Thus, an unmodifiable view collection is not necessarily immutable. However, if the backing collection of an unmodifiable view is effectively immutable, or if the only reference to the backing collection is through an unmodifiable view, the view can be considered effectively immutable.

As the `Collections.unmodifiableList` returns a `unmodifiable view` of the backing list, it is still possible to modify the backing list which will impact the unmodifiable list. Now, the list is in turn backed by the array provided in the `Arrays.asList` method. So, everything depends on `this.toArray()`. As it is inside a default method of the `Stream` interface, it is dependent on the actual implementation of the stream whether `toArray()` returns a something modifiable or not. That's why it needs to be copied.

Comment: "it is still possible to modify the backing list" - yes, but what is this backing list? It is the list returned by `Arrays.asList(this.toArray())`. How can you possibly modify this list? It seems quite unmodifiable to me, as it's not accessible, it's something that gets created inside an API method and never gets out except through the `unmodifiable` wrapper.

Comment: @k314159 This is a default method in an interface. There is no guarantee that `toArray` will return a brand new array. If the `Stream` implementation reuses array instances, that will retroactively change the list returned by `Arrays.asList` (since it's only a wrapper around the underlying array). As such, the point is to 1) get the array, 2) create an adapter to make it usable as a list, and 3) make a safe copy of that list without any connection to the original array.

(Yes, reusing arrays is silly, but a default method can't just make wild assumptions about implementation details.)

Comment: Thanks. It seems that all the Stream implementations inside the Java API (in the OpenJDK) define `toArray()` to create a brand new array. However, I guess you're saying there's nothing to prevent a user from writing their own Stream implementation that returns an existing array, and therefore it has to be copied.

Comment: @k314159 correct. The implementations create brand new arrays, but as said before, the specification doesn't require it, and that allows other implementations to return the same instance.

Answer (score 2):

### When talking about ***safe***, we usually refer to whether the object is [immutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html)

- `unmodifiableList` -> **unmodifiable** here only guarantee caller can not change the state of wrapped list, and change of source will still be reflected in the wrapped list.
- `new ArrayList<>` -> **defensive copy** means modifying source will not change the state of the copy and vice versa.
- **unmodifiable** + **defensive copy** -> **immutable**, you can assume the list always hold the same list of object reference.

### Concrete example to demonstrate the difference

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class UnmodifiableListCopy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] source = new String[]{"dummy"};
        List<String> unmodifiable = unmodifiableListWithoutCopy(source);
        List<String> immutable = unmodifiableListWithCopy(source);
        System.out.println("unmodifiable:" + unmodifiable);
        System.out.println("immutable:" + immutable);
        source[0] = "modified";
        System.out.println("--- change source ---");
        System.out.println("unmodifiable:" + unmodifiable);
        System.out.println("immutable:" + immutable);
    }

    private static <T> List<T> unmodifiableListWithoutCopy(T[] arr) {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(arr));
    }

    private static <T> List<T> unmodifiableListWithCopy(T[] arr) {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr)));
    }
}
```

You should see below when you run the code.

```
unmodifiable:[dummy]
immutable:[dummy]
--- change source ---
unmodifiable:[modified]
immutable:[dummy]
```

Reference

- [Immutable vs Unmodifiable collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8892350/7928721)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for creating a new ArrayList in the implementation you provided is to ensure that the returned list is truly unmodifiable. The Arrays.asList method returns a fixed-size list backed by the original array.

An alternative and more modern approach to obtaining an unmodifiable list is to use the Collectors.toUnmodifiableList() method from the Stream API. For example:

> Arrays.stream(this.toArray()).collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());

This approach directly produces an unmodifiable list without the need for creating an intermediate ArrayList. I hope this suggestion proves helpful.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting reminder about the existence of `toUnmodifiableList()`. However `Stream.toList()`, introduced in Java 16, is more "modern" than `Collectors.toUnmodifiableList()` (Java 10). And when you write `collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList())` IntelliJ IDEA suggests to change it to `toList()`.

Comment: also be aware that `Collectors.toUnmodifiableList()` does **not** allow `null` elements; while these are allowed by `toList()`

Answer (score -3):

I don't have an answer but I find the implementation of `Arrays.asList()` funny, since it also creates a list inside:

```
    public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
        return new ArrayList<>(a);
    }
```

I wonder what happened, maybe its one of those: "this only applies to certain VMs so cant be guaranteed"

If you are not writing a library I wouldn't mind to much to be honest. `T` would also need to be immutable for true safety btw.

EDIT: intresting stuff, apparently this `ArrayList` is a different `ArrayList`, *nothing strange*

Comment: The `ArrayList` used in `Arrays` is not the normal `java.util.ArrayList`, but an unrelated implementation defined inside `Arrays` itself that just happens to also be called `ArrayList`. As such, a `j.u.ArrayList` being created using an `Arrays.ArrayList` is nothing strange.