# Why does Collectors.toList() not guarantee mutability

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, collectors

The implementation of toList() clearly returns an ArrayList which does guarantee mutability:

```
public static <T>
Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toList() {
    return new CollectorImpl<>(ArrayList::new, List::add,
                               (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },
                               CH_ID);
}
```

but the JavaDoc of toList reads as:

```
/**
 * Returns a {@code Collector} that accumulates the input elements into a
 * new {@code List}. There are no guarantees on the type, mutability,
 * serializability, or thread-safety of the {@code List} returned; if more
 * control over the returned {@code List} is required, use {@link #toCollection(Supplier)}.
 *
 * @param <T> the type of the input elements
 * @return a {@code Collector} which collects all the input elements into a
 * {@code List}, in encounter order
 */
```

Why is mutability not guaranteed? Am I missing cases where the returned collection could be immutable? is it safe to use Collectors.toList() when mutability is required of the returned collection?

Comment: As you've said it is an *implementation detail*. The contract (Javadoc) doesn't say it will be an ArrayList.

Comment: In other words, the implementation can change in future (or alternative) JDKs. You should only rely on specified behavior. Though judging by the introduction of `toUnmodifiableList()` in later versions, I'm guessing they were afraid to actually make the change because people do implicitly rely on the mutability of `toList()` (I've seen plenty of cases myself). But see the discussion in these [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49106767/collectors-tounmodifiablelist-in-java-10#comment85464246_49106767).

Comment: I tend to presume that it is immutable.  Then I don't have think about `Collectors.toList()` as mutable and `Stream.toList()` as immutable.  If I want I can either add the output to a `new ArrayList<>() ` or just specifiy it via `Collectors.toCollection()`

Comment: To your last question, you can safely conclude from the specification that it is _not_ safe to use `toList()` where mutability is guaranteed, because the spec plainly tells you not to assume this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Because the authors said so

> Why is mutability not guaranteed?

Because the designers of the [`Collectors.toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()) method chose so.

> The implementation of toList() clearly returns an ArrayList

That fact is a mere implementation detail.

And that detail applies only to the one version of the one implementation that you studied. Other versions, and other implementations, may use something other than `ArrayList`.

Any implementation is subject to change, within the limits of the contract promised by the documentation. All that matters is the behavior promised by that documentation.

To quote the Javadoc:

> Returns a `Collector` that accumulates the input elements into a new `List`. There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the `List` returned; if more control over the returned List is required, use `toCollection(Supplier)`.

Seems crystal clear to me. You have been promised that the resulting `List` may be mutable or may be immutable. You’ve been told not to rely on either being the case.

#### Modifiable

If you want a mutable/modifiable `List`,  make a new one from the list generated by your collector. Pass the collected list to the constructor of a new list object.

```
List< Whatever > list = new ArrayList<>( collectorList ) ;
```

Or, as the Javadoc above suggests, you can  pass `Supplier` to render a list implementation of your choice. Call [`Collectors.toCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection(java.util.function.Supplier)). See [section 3.3](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-collectors#3-collectorstocollection) of the tutorial on Baeldung.com.

For example:

```
toCollection( ArrayList :: new )
```

#### Unmodifiable

If you want an immutable/[unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) list, I suggest  calling [`List.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)).

```
List< Whatever > list = List.copyOf( collectorList ) ;
```

That method promises to return:

> … an unmodifiable List containing the elements of the given `Collection`, in its iteration order.

But there is a catch: No nulls allowed. Two alternatives for a list with nulls:

- In Java 16+,  call [`Stream#toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) for an unmodifiable list tolerating nulls.
- In Java 8-15, use [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)).

---

By the way, Java 21 brought [sequenced collections](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431). So the more general interface of `List` is `SequencedCollection`.

```
SequencedCollection< Whatever > sequence = List.copyOf( collectorList ) ;
```

Comment: A better option would be `toCollection(ArrayList::new)`.

Comment: @shmosel Thanks. I added a bit on your solution.

Comment: *But the passed unmodifiable list may actually be a view onto a modifiable list underneath.* I think you might be confusing with `Collections.unmodifiableList()`. The static `List` factories don't return views. And who would have access to the underlying list anyway?

Comment: @shmosel Yes, you are correct. I deleted that portion. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I've always assumed that Collectors.toList() was intended to return a modifiable list and and for an unmodifiable list I always used collectingAndThen toUnmodifibleList. I have just now read the Documentation and it seemed very weird to me that the Contract did not guarantee mutability because collectingAndThen toModifiableList was such a common practice, hence the question.

Comment: If you want an immutable list supporting `null`, you can simply call [`toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) on the `Stream` (since Java 16).

Comment: @Holger I added your info to the Answer. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why the Java guys are so stingy with QoL methods. Just add #toModifiableList when you add #toList, or give #toList an optional boolean parameter to make it modifiable.

Comment: @MartinFörsterling I can only guess at  the Java API designers’ intentions. I suppose one reason might be that in the decades of programming, we have found it generally best to default to immutability until a reason for mutability has been identified. Another reason is that creating a mutable collection is so easy: Just pass the immutable collection to the constructor of your mutable collection: `List< Foo > list = new ArrayList<>( unmodifiableList ) ;`.  Another very simple way to create a mutable collection from a stream is shown in the Answer here: `.toCollection( ArrayList :: new )`.

Comment: @MartinFörsterling And another reason might be that if you want a mutable collection, you must be planning on mutating it. If you are going to mutate, then you likely have concerns over the behaviors and performance of various implementations available for mutable collections. For example, `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` have very different behaviors and performance. And so you likely want to specify a particular implementation rather than rely on some arbitrary choice of implementation made by a "toModifiableList` method. The `.toCollection( ArrayList :: new )` lets you specify implementation.

Comment: @BasilBourque Those are good points, but mixing collection implementation with mutability is meh. If I care about implementation, I can always use .toCollection(ArrayList::new) or whatever, that's true. But the old Collectors.toList() did not guerantee mutability, which is the worst kind of method contract. As it is in Java, things are

Comment: This makes it clear that Java is awfully lacking in that regard because the compiler can't warn me if I mutate an immutable list I get from toList(). I can only see an exception at runtime, which is terrible. 
That's why I think the method name should make it explicit whether the returned collection is mutable or not, and the jdk should also provice type support for immutable collections. Guava has provided this for years, but Java catches up much too slowly.